# Не запускается Docker-compose хотя раньше всё работало хорошо

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

User:~$ docker-compose up

cannot update snap namespace: cannot create symlink in "/etc/docker": existing file in the way
snap-update-ns failed with code 1
`

Причём не запускается любой фаил docker compose

Comment: Ты докер через snap что ли ставил?

Comment: Да ставил через снап, в обычных репозиториях не было!

Comment: Да неужели? https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогла эта команда:

```
snap disable docker && snap enable  docker
```

Comment: Выглядит как проблема snap-пакета а не самого докера.